# Problema ao passar versão no maven via property

Tags: java, maven

Estou tentando fazer uma modificação em um projeto para permitir passar uma property e gerar o pacote com a versão que foi passada. Ex: mvn package install -Dversion.app=0.0.1
Porém estou com um problema na hora de gerar o projeto B que tem duas dependências do projeto A (dois módulos). O projeto A gera os artefatos e instala na .m2, mas quando executo o mesmo comando para o projeto B ele não consegue achar as dependências. Na verdade, pelo que identifiquei ele tenta buscar pelo caminho errado (/.m2/repository/br/projeto/${version.app}), reconhecendo a property como uma string, mas no projeto A funciona perfeitamente.

Enfim, meu problema é esse, preciso usar esse comando nos dois projetos e conseguir passar o valor da property:
mvn package install -Dversion.app=0.0.1

Projeto A:

```
<groupId>br.projeto</groupId>
<artifactId>projeto-a</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>${version.app}</version>
<name>Projeto A - Parent</name>

<modules>
    <module>core-model</module>
    <module>core-ejb</module>
    <module>web-api</module>
</modules>
```

Projeto B:

```
<groupId>br.projeto</groupId>
<artifactId>projeto-b</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>${version.app}</version>
<name>Projeto B - Parent</name>

<modules>
    <module>outro-modulo</module>
    <module>outroweb-api</module>
</modules>

 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.projeto</groupId>
        <artifactId>core-model</artifactId>
        <version>${version.app}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.projeto</groupId>
        <artifactId>core-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>${version.app}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Módulo - outroweb-api do Projeto B:

```
<artifactId>outroweb-api</artifactId>
<parent>
    <groupId>br.projeto</groupId>
    <artifactId>projeto-b</artifactId>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    <version>${version.app}</version><!--Isso não é permitido-->
</parent>

<packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.projeto</groupId>
        <artifactId>core-model</artifactId>
        <version>${version.app}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.projeto</groupId>
        <artifactId>core-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>${version.app}</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependencies>
```

Enfim,

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia utilizar os [comandos de release](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/update-versions.html) do Maven para atualizar as versões, da forma como está fazendo não vai funcionar.

O motivo por não compilar e apresentar erro é que apenas com a variável não é possível localizar a versão pai do seu artefato.

Para atualizar tanto o projeto pai quanto os submódulos, você pode utilizar este comando:

```
mvn release:update-versions -DautoVersionSubmodules=true
```

Com isso um prompt será apresentado para input da nova versão.

Caso você esteja rodando isso de forma [não interativa](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/non-interactive-release.html), você também pode especificar a versão via linha de comando:

```
mvn --batch-mode release:update-versions -DdevelopmentVersion=1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Lembrando que você também pode especificar a versão de release utilizando o `-DreleaseVersion=1.2` por exemplo.

Mais detalhes constam na documentação.

---

Esqueci de mencionar, utilizando esses comandos você não precisa de variáveis, o Maven já entende onde estão as versões no `pom.xml` e troca sem nenhum problema :)

---

Já que você deseja ter uma versão parent dinâmica, é possível utilizar um recurso de `revision` desde o Maven 3.5.0, o qual se chama de [Maven CI Friendly Versions](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html).

Com esse recurso você pode executar o comando da seguinte forma:

```
mvn -Drevision=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT clean package
```

E no pom de seus módulos seria assim:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>meu.lindo.modulo</groupId>
  <artifactId>modulo-pai</artifactId>
  <version>${revision}</version>
 </parent>
```

Se ainda assim com este recurso você não conseguir realizar o esperado, a única solução seria criar um script ou ferramenta para interpretar o `pom.xml` e trocar conforme você deseja.

Comment: Consegue me explicar o por que apenas com a variável não é possível encontrar o pom pai no caso do projeto B? O objetivo é que eu não faça o que o comando fez (scanner todos pom e fazer o replace), e sim conseguir fazer como eu fiz no primeiro projeto a, passar a property/variável e gerar tanto o ear como os submodulos na versão informada.

Comment: @L. Luan E no que isso ajudaria? O objetivo do versionamento é manter todos os módulos na mesma versão, o comando de release realiza exatamente isso, altera a versão do módulo pai, através do número desejado, atualiza as dependências dos submódulos para a versão desejada, e atualiza também os artefatos relacionados no pom para a nova versão

Comment: Adicionei mais alguns detalhes na resposta, uma outra forma já que você deseja ter a versão do pom variável.